# Reverse Regex with lookahead to find matched string

Tags: regex

I have this Regex (given by someone else) and I need to test with a matched string.

```
"(?<=[H|h]at [\'|\""]).*?(?=[\'|\""])"
```

However, I could not figure out how it will match

I thought `"Hat 'test'"` would do it but it didn't match:

http://regexr.com/3s879

Can you give me some guidance?

Thanks

Comment: The first thing I notice is that the regex was obviously written by someone who has no idea what they're doing, so I would recommend throwing it away and writing your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's can break this down.

---

First it looks like we are trying to make sure the word "hat" or "Hat" followed by a single quote comes before anything we matche.

- `(?<=...)` Is a look-back, meaning it is ensuring its contents exist before our match.
- `[H|h]at [\'|\""]` Appears to have been written poorly

  1. `[H|h]at` will match with 'Hat', 'hat' and '|at'. If only "Hat" and "hat" are desired, then the '|' should be removed.

     - `|` Is not considered 'or' within square brackets, as they are meant to make a list of possible matches
  2. `[\'|\""]` is also falling victim to the same issue, and the escape characters are not needed.

A better way to match the word "hat" followed by a quote would be:

```
[Hh]at\s['"]
```

---

Next it wants to match anything, so it uses `.*?`

The `?` makes it *lazy*, meaning it will match as few as possible before the next step.

---

Finally, it uses a look-ahead to find the closing quote. Again, falling into the same issues as above. `(?=[\'|\""])` should be replaced with:

```
(?=['"])
```

---

It seems whoever wrote that regex made a few mistakes. Here is a [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dKHC1t/4) with my changes, and here is a [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dKHC1t/5) before my changes. I included example strings from [Pete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/639716/pete)'s answer to help show the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Among the [many possible matches](https://regex101.com/r/naIlZl/1) are:

```
Hat 'pretty much anything in apostrophes'
hat 'pretty much anything in apostrophes'
|at 'pretty much anything in apostrophes'
Hat |pretty much anything in pipes|
hat |pretty much anything in pipes|
|at |pretty much anything in pipes|
Hat "pretty much anything in double quotes"
hat "pretty much anything in double quotes"
|at "pretty much anything in double quotes"
Hat ""pretty much anything in double double quotes""
hat ""pretty much anything in double double quotes""
|at ""pretty much anything in double double quotes""
Hat "and pretty much anything in any combination of those|
hat |and pretty much anything in any combination of those'
|at ""and pretty much anything in any combination of those"
```

and the actual matched text is whatever is between the delimiter characters (`('|"|""|\|)`).

For what it's worth, if you have the chance to rewrite this one in your codebase, now would probably be an opportune time. :)